# Can "AはBに影響されない" and "AはBに影響しない" ever have the same meaning?

Tags: particle-に, particle-は, passive-voice

In a conversation, I wanted to say:

> **A** does not affect **B**.

We'd been discussing **A** and **B** for awhile, and I said:

> (1) **A**は**B**を影響{えいきょう}しない。

I was stopped and told to say:

> (2) **A**は**B**に影響されない。

then she mentioned that I also could say:

> (3) **A**は**B**に影響しない。

I'm really puzzled about that exchange. Maybe I completely misunderstood her Japanese.

Can #2 and #3 ever have the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A does not affect B" is translated as "AはBに影響しない" and "AはBに影響を与えない" , so (1) is unnatural.

(2) and (3) are different. (2) is translated as "A isn't affected by B".